# Ability to "Login as" other users via REST API?

Tags: rest-api, authentication, login

Salesforce allows the ability to "login as" other users via the Setup UI assuming the logged-in user has the proper permissions to do so. Does the REST API expose the "login as" functionality? Having a really difficult time telling whether this is doable via the REST API's outside the UI.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

If you use the JWT OAuth2.0 flow though, you can set up your connected app to allow you to log in as an arbitrary user. I'm not sure if you need to select the "admin-approved users are pre-authorized" option (and then add profiles that are pre-approved) or not, and you will need to go through a flow that can return a refresh token (like the web-server flow) for your connected app before you can use the JWT flow.

If you only need to test what happens when a particular user accesses a resource, then that should be able to be taken care of with unit tests and `System.runAs()`.